# Simple Injector Dependency Resolution Error - Could not load file or assembly System.Web.Http

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I am following onion architecture and using `simple injector` in the DependencyResolution Project. Here is my architecture:

```
1-Core
     - Domain Classes
     - Repository Interfaces
     - Service Interfaces
2-Infrastructure
     - Data
     - Dependency Resolution
     - Repository Interfaces Implementation
     - Service Interfaces Implementation
3-WebApi
     - Web Api Project
4-WebClient
     - My AngularJs App
5-Test
     - Test Project
```

**StartUp.cs**

```
public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Here I am getting error at runtime.
            SimpleInjectorInitializer.Initialize(app);
            ConfigureAuth(app);
        }
    }
```

**SimpleInjectorInitializer.Initialize**

```
public static Container Initialize(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var container = GetInitializeContainer(app);

            // This is an extension method from the integration package.
            container.RegisterWebApiControllers(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

            container.Verify();

            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver =
                new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

            return container;
        }
```

Here I added reference to `System.Web, System.Web.Http, System.Web.Http.Host` taken from WebApi project.

I put the path of the output of my DependencyResolution project to WebApi bin and set the value of owinstart in `web.config`.

Here is the error I am getting:

> An exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in
>   Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.dll but was not handled in user
>   code
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

**Edit:**

Here is App.Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably missing a binding redirect in the application's configuration file. In most cases, the NuGet package manager will set the binding redirects correctly for you, for sometimes it fails to do so.

The binding redirect you need in your config file looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" 
            culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-{version}" newVersion="{version}"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Note that you need to replace the `{version}` placeholders for the actual version you are referencing.

Comment: In my case, SimpleInjector correctly added the assembly identity for System.Web.Http - I had to delete the `bin` and `obj` folders so that it started using the latest web.config.

Comment: Dude, you saved my life! I want to give you ten thumbs up!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are using same version of SimpleInjector in whole projects that you used Dependency Injection? I faced with  similar error and I noticed that  SimpleInjectors old version was used in one project. It started to work after I update SimpleInjector by nuget to new version.